# ContactsUI.Framework Crash on IOS 8

Tags: iphone, ios8, crash, ios9, contacts-framework

There are two new frameworks for fetching Contacts from ContactsBook in Xcode 7 sdk.
i.e Contacts.framework & ContactsUI.framework

I have added these frameworks in my app. For IOS 9 it is working fine.
But when i try to run my app in iPhone 5 with IOS 8 then the app is crashing on start.

The error is :-

**dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ContactsUI.framework/ContactsUI**

I can understand that the framework or library is not available in IOS 8 but how about backward compatibility?

How will i be able to use my app in IOS 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not give the backward compatibility because the `ContactsUI` is not available before the version iOS 9

Its only available after the iOS 9

Check the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerViewController_Class/index.html):

```
Available in iOS 9.0 and later
```

Comment: Thats ok but then how can i run my app in IOS8 and IOS9 simultaneously?

Comment: @Kiran You just have to check the version of the iOS and do code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the framework that's not available on iOS 8 is set as Optional

[image]